# Parameter with multiple values Python

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have a function `foo` that have 3 parameters `par1`, `par2` and `par3`.

```py
def foo(par1, par2, par3):
          ...
```

The inputs are given by the user via string, and that `par2` parameter, can have more than one word. For example `lorem ipsum`.

Input example:

```py
>> 'test   lorem ipsum    3'     # The "spare" spaces are just for separating.
    ^^^  |     ^^^     | ^^^  
    par1 |     par2    | par3
```

`par2` doesn't have a fixed size of words.

There's a way to separate this parameters?

Comment: Dear @ThRnk, why do you mean by 'separate this parameters without forcing the user to use " " on par2'? If these parameters are given through command-line-interfce I'n afraid there is no other option, rather than to use " around parameter 2

Comment: How are you going to determine how many words should go into the 2nd parameter?

Comment: @AvivYaniv for example `test "lorem ipsum" 3`.

Comment: lets suppose you call your function like so :  `foo('test   lorem ipsum    3')` - the you have only one parameter and you'll get an error. You could however call it   `foo(*('test   lorem ipsum    3'.split("   ")))`

Comment: ``import re; foo(*re.split("\s{2,}", 'test   lorem ipsum    3'))``, split by more than one space & use unpacking.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk that's the point, I know that the first and last parameter are made only by 1 argument, all in the center will be the `par2`, I don't know if there's a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def func(par1, par2, par3):
    print(par1)
    print(par2)
    print(par3)

i = "test lorem ipsum 3"
inputs = list(i.split())
func(inputs[0], inputs[1:-1], inputs[-1])
```

Output:

```
test
['lorem', 'ipsum']
3
```

Edit: Output added. This will split the input by spaces and give the middle words to par2. Word 1 and the last word will get assigned to par1 and par3 respectively.

Comment: The answer I need is something on this way, it's a good base tho.

Comment: @guidot func(*inputs) will not work because there will be 4 inputs for 3 func arguments, I tested it with multiple spaces in between and it worked on python 3.6.4.